# Rewrite author URL to example.com/u/{user_id}/{username}/

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to rewrite the author URL to use the author ID to determine who's page is being displayed, and then automatically add the username after the author ID.

The URL should ignore the username to prevent username changes from breaking old profile links, but should also redirect to the current used username.

```
example.com/u/{user_id}/            ->  example.com/u/{user_id}/{username}/
example.com/u/{user_id}/{anything}/ ->  example.com/u/{user_id}/{username}/
```

So far, I have some code which does allow the URL to browse to author pages, but it doesn't work when adding anything after the ID in the url.

```
// It works!
example.com/u/{user_id}/

// Works, but shouldn't work
example.com/u/{username}/

// Doesn't work...
example.com/u/{user_id}/{anything}/
```

Here's my current code.

```
add_action('init','change_user_permalink');
function change_user_permalink() {  
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'u';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%/';

    add_rewrite_rule('^u/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?author=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
/**
 * Replace %author_id% by author_id.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @param   string  $link
 * @param   int     $author_id
 */
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse_298572_change_author_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse_298572_change_author_link( $link, $author_id ) {
    $link = str_replace( '%author_id%', $author_id, $link );
    return $link;
}

/**
 * Rewrite the user link.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 */
add_action('init', 'wpse_298572_rewrite_user_link');
function wpse_298572_rewrite_user_link() {  
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'u';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base .'/%author_id%/%author%/';

    add_rewrite_rule('^u/([\d]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)\/?$', 'index.php?author=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

/**
 * Redirect to full user link.
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 */
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_298572_user_permalink_redirect');
function wpse_298572_user_permalink_redirect() {    
    global $wp;

    // Check if on author page
    $author = get_query_var('author');

    if ( !isset($author) ) {
        return;
    }

    preg_match("/\/?u\/([\d]+)\/?([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)?\/?(.*)$/", $wp->request, $matches);

    if ( isset($matches[1]) && $user = get_user_by('ID', $matches[1]) ) {       
        // Don't redirect if url already matches the correct name
        if ( $matches[2] == $user->user_nicename ) {
            return;
        }

        $author_permalink = get_author_posts_url($user->ID) . $matches[3];

        wp_safe_redirect($author_permalink, 301);
        exit();     
    }
}
```